# What is the fastest way to identify the two nearest linestrings using PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, point, postgis-2.0, linestring

I want to be able to identify the closest roads to two points that are generated through geocoding (a start and end address). The points will likely be near a linestring. Two approaches that I have been experimenting with are:

```
-- Method 1:
SELECT 
    id
FROM 
    routing
WHERE
    ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(ST_Setsrid(ST_Makepoint(-6.17706680000, 53.300791),4326), 900913), geom, 50.0) 
ORDER BY , 
    ST_distance(geom_way, ST_Transform(ST_Setsrid(ST_Makepoint(-6.17706680000, 53.300791),4326), 900913))
LIMIT 1;
--Time: 228  ms 

-- Method 2:
SELECT  
        id
FROM 
        routing
WHERE
        ST_Intersects(geom, ST_buffer(ST_Transform(ST_Setsrid(ST_Makepoint(-6.17706680000, 53.300791),4326), 900913), 50))
ORDER BY , 
        ST_Distance(geom, ST_Transform(ST_Setsrid(ST_Makepoint(-6.17706680000, 53.300791),4326), 900913))  
LIMIT 1;
--Time: 248 ms
```

While both of these are quite fast, I'm unsure if this is the best way of performing this calculation. Both methods assume that the geo-coded point will be `<50m` away from a road. I also want to figure out the best way of finding two roads and cannot think of an alternative, other than to run to separate queries sequentially, which would mean that it takes ~0.5 seconds in total using the current set-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of use ST_distance use the operator **<->** [It makes use](http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/) of the GIST index so it should be faster than use st_distance.

Comment: Does it make sense to still use `ST_DWithin()` when using the `<->` operator?

Comment: If you need, to discard those results where the distance is greater than 50m yes. If you not need that, probably it will be faster skip that.